# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' in data binding(gridview)

Tags: c#, casting

This is the line where the String gets assigned to a boolean property:

```
chkreputative.Checked = gvmanufacturers.DataKeys[rowindex]["IsReputative"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `ToString()` call, and apply the correct cast. You are trying to assign a `String` value to a `Boolean` value, that's why you get the exception.

Depending on what type the `DataKeys` object is, you can try some of the following:

```
chkreputative.Checked = (bool)gvmanufacturers.DataKeys[rowindex]["IsReputative"];

chkreputative.Checked = Boolean.Parse(gvmanufacturers.DataKeys[rowindex]["IsReputative"]);

chkreputative.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(gvmanufacturers.DataKeys[rowindex]["IsReputative"]);
```